# Prevent focus on Expand More button after content is inserted in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to list out a long name list inside my page while showing all names at first is not desirable.
So I try to add an **expand more button** on it.

[image]

However, using a button will keep the browser focus on that button after it's pressed, left the button position unchanged on the screen while the name was inserted before that button.

On the other hand, using any, not focusable element (eg. div with onclick function) will do the desired behavior but lost the accessibility at all. Making the "button" only clickable but not focusable.

How do I make the button flushed to list bottom like the snippet div block does? Or is there a better choice to expand the existing list?

```js
const myArray = [
  'Alex',
  'Bob',
  'Charlie',
  'Dennis',
  'Evan',
  'Floron',
  'Gorgious',
  'Harris',
  'Ivan',
  'Jennis',
  'Kurber',
  'Lowrance',
]
const ExpandList = (props) => {
  const [idx, setIdx] = React.useState(8)
  const handleExpand = e => {
    setIdx(idx + 1)
  }
  return <div className='demo'>
    <h1>Name List</h1>
    {myArray.slice(0,idx).map(
      name => <p key={name}>{name}</p>
    )}
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleExpand} children='Button Expand' className='pointer' />
      <div onClick={handleExpand} className='pointer'>Div Expand</div>
    </div>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<ExpandList/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.demo>p {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #666;
  background: #3331;
}

.demo>div>div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #666;
  background: #3331;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pointer:hover {
  background-color: #6663;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' class='demo'>hello</div>
```

Comment: blur the button on click and insert the content after that?

Comment: @0x2D9A3 Thanks for suggestion. It should work, but it also makes the logic more complicated so I currently don't consider reordering element.

Comment: You can try incrementing `idx` with a small delay like this: `setTimeout(() => setIdx(idx + 1), 0);`. (Btw, what's the browser you are using, because I can't reproduce the issue in Chrome or Firefox when I run your code snippet)

Comment: Chrome `86.0.4240.75` and Windows 10 (2004), also Edge(Chromium). Disabling all pulgin. (Surprisingly it's hardware/platform dependable?)

Comment: The setTimeout won't work, since the focus item is still that expand button. Unless user click on other position between the interval, Browser still focus/stick on the button.

Comment: Ah, now I was able to reproduce this in Edge. `setTimeout` did not work indeed. I'd either go for `e.target.blur()` in your click handler, or inline it like this: `<button onClick={(ev) => { ev.target.blur(); handleExpand(ev)}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing focus from the button in the click handler is probably the most elegant approach: `e.target.blur()`. It will work on any HTML element, whether it is focusable or not (as with the `div` in your case).

```js
const myArray = [
  'Alex',
  'Bob',
  'Charlie',
  'Dennis',
  'Evan',
  'Floron',
  'Gorgious',
  'Harris',
  'Ivan',
  'Jennis',
  'Kurber',
  'Lowrance',
]
const ExpandList = (props) => {
  const [idx, setIdx] = React.useState(8)
  const handleExpand = e => {
    e.target.blur()
    setIdx(idx + 1)
  }
  return <div className='demo'>
    <h1>Name List</h1>
    {myArray.slice(0,idx).map(
      name => <p key={name}>{name}</p>
    )}
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleExpand} children='Button Expand' className='pointer' />
      <div onClick={handleExpand} className='pointer'>Div Expand</div>
    </div>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<ExpandList/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.demo>p {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #666;
  background: #3331;
}

.demo>div>div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #666;
  background: #3331;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pointer:hover {
  background-color: #6663;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' class='demo'>hello</div>
```

Comment: And also I have notice that when pressed twice, after the second click it will still focus on my button. So I add `document.activeElement.blur()` to lost focus on button as well.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @MiKo, temporally unmount the button after click and set a timeout to add it back seems to do the work. Since browser lose the focus on original expand button, this will keep content flush down without focusing the original button:

```js
const ExpandList = (props) => {
  const [idx, setIdx] = React.useState(8)
  const [showBtn, setShowBtn] = React.useState(true)
  const handleExpand = e => {
    setShowBtn(false)
    setIdx(idx + 1)
    setTimeout(() => setShowBtn(true), 10)
  }
  return <div className='demo'>
    <h1>Name List</h1>
    {myArray.slice(0,idx).map(
      name => <p key={name}>{name}</p>
    )}
    {showBtn?
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleExpand} children='Button Expand' className='pointer' />
        <div onClick={handleExpand} className='pointer'>Div Expand</div>
      </div> :
      <div></div>
    }
  </div>
}
```

But I'm still looking a method that doesn't need to 'unmount' a thing which should be there all time.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a bit of an overkill! I'd go with `blur()` as a much simpler solution.

Comment: Yes, blur is more elegant, would you like to post it as an answer then I can mark that one as accepted one? Also, in my real work with Material UI ButtonBase component, `e.target.blur()` need to go with `e.stopPropogation()` to make it work.

Comment: Posted as an answer. Good catch, `e.stopPropagation()` can often be a good addition when dealing with buttons and links.